# Cross object formula field for multi select picklist

Tags: formula, cross-object

I want a field on accounts that shows the only one of the values of a custom multi-select picklist on contacts. I have never written a formula before. I found my custom multi select picklist field using the advanced formula field tool, but I'm not sure what the syntax should be around it. I'm thinking it should be something like If the picklist value of the custom field is trustee, then return the value trustee. Here's what I have so far:

```
IF
   ISPICKVAL(npe01__One2OneContact__r.Contact_Type__c, trustee)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope you are doing well.
Multi-select picklist fields are only supported in certain functions.
In this case you should use this formula:

```
IF(INCLUDES(npe01__One2OneContact__r.Contact_Type__c, 'trustee'),'trustee','')
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked